# Not able to read/pass JS value to server in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm fetching value from Mysql in DropDown. Based on user selection a table should be populated.
But whatever I'm selecting in dropdown, it's not getting sent to server.

Please find below code:

Fetch value in dropdown

```
<?php 
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name FROM restaurants;");
                    echo "<select name='sub1' id='resdropdown' onchange = 'showMenu(this.value)'>";
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

Script to send value to server

```
function showMenu(str) {
     /* var x = document.getElementById('resdropdown');
        str = x.value;
        alert(str);  */
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var method = "GET";

        var asynchronous = true;
        var data = str;

        ajax.open(method, "test.php?q="+data, asynchronous);

        //sending ajax request
        ajax.send();


        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("testajaxid").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                alert(str);
            }
        };

    }
```

Get Response from server

```
        $q = $_GET['data'];

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM items where  id = '".$q."'");


        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$row["name"].'</td><td>'.$row["price"].'</td>';                      
            echo '<td><div class="input-field col s12"><label for='.$row["id"].' class="">Quantity</label>';
            echo '<input id="'.$row["id"].'" name="'.$row['id'].'" type="text" data-error=".errorTxt'.$row["id"].'"><div class="errorTxt'.$row["id"].'"></div></td></tr>';
        }
```

Comment: `"test.php?q="+data` =>  `$q = $_GET['data'];` will not work

_This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0):

Your $_GET variable should be `$_GET['q']` instead of `$_GET['data']`, because you set the URL to `test.php?q=data`.

Also, you shouldn't put raw user provided data in SQL queries, use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead, because of risks of SQL injection.